# form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" results in error 403

Tags: php, forms, xampp

I got an exaple of submting images to a submit images to a dB http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_%28blob_storage%29.xml#search
This php script above Works really fine when I execute it on MAMP. But when I execute on a PC with XAMPP I just can't get it working gives the 403 error on XAMPP. Checked the php.ini file on the XAMPP installation and read something like short tags = on. Also noticed many people use

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post"
    </form>
```

insted of

```
    <form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

on the example on:http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_%28blob_storage%29.xml#search
Any clue to get it working on the PC with XAMPP.

Thanks in advance JPA

Comment: If you submitting to same page, just simply don't declare the action.

Comment: ajreal -but then how the script will execute the actions to upload or delete images if the script is based on the following:if   ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

Comment: don't misunderstand, remove the action only, not the method

Answer (score 1):

Error 403 means access violation. Thus you need to check server configuration regarding access to the url contained in $PHP_SELF, file uploading and temporary folder.

As you know when we're submitting multipart/form-data request, PHP tries to store file in temporary folder until script finish its execution.
Troubles can occure if server don't have access rights for temporary folder. The other variant is file upload can be totally disabled in PHP configuration.

Check you don't have file_uploads=Off in your php.ini
Also check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, they can forbid your file upload if the filesize is greater than supposed.