# Xampp error 403 forbidden access

Tags: php, xampp

i have the following code when i access it using localhost its work fine but when i click on save button it produce the following error.

Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>`
<title>Student Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stdform.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>




<div class="main">



<form name="stform" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label for="ID">Student ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="ID"><br>
<label for="name">Student Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="stname" id="name"><br>
<label for="stpr">Study Program: </label>
<input type="text" name="Program" id="stpr"><br>
<label for="samtr">Sammester: </label>
<select id="samtr">
    <option >select sammester</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
</select><br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Record">
 </form>
 </div>
</center>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say the reason is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [form action="<?=$PHP\_SELF?>" results in error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411231/form-action-php-self-results-in-error-403)

Comment: Please stop or close your XAMPP and run by right clicking run as an administrator option, and then try to execute this, still you face the problem right here error....

Comment: not duplicate of above  question

Comment: ok  trying  this method

Comment: If you are still facing problem then share your apache logs from XAMPP.

Comment: not working that's way also

Comment: now server is not starting again and no error message has been displayed

Comment: can share what error is this showing. Just go to the Xampp tool and in-front of apache you will see logs , click on logs and edit your question and add logs in the bottom of your question